# Java: Applying probability constraints on Random()

Tags: java, random, constraints, artificial-intelligence, probability

I've never been particularly savvy with the Java random functions.

I'm using

`int myrandom = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(x, y+1)`

Where the value of myrandom will be calculated between the variables x and y.

The value it's self is not entirely relevant, and I will probably just set it to 0 and 1000, and then run an algorithm to interpret that value.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

            if( randmods[i].gtr_less(choice) ){
                choice = i;
                break;

            }else{
                continue;

            }
        }
```

Where the function is simply:

```
public boolean gtr_less(int value){

    if(value > mod_min && value < mod_max){
        return true;

    }else{

        return false;
    }

}
```

The basic method is assessing all of the possibilities using `if(rand > x && rand < y)`

The problem is, I want to constrain the modifiers I place on each range within the 0-1000.

So if it was 10 cases and they were:

Z>0 && Z<100, Z>100 && Z<200, Z>200 && Z<300...

... and so on, I want to change the constraints to say, Z>0 && Z<110, Z>110 Z<210.

As you can see, and probably guess, manipulating the data in this way is a huge pain, and I am certain there must be a better way to do this, probably using modulus.

The main issue is that I have to modify /all/ of the cases when I only want to change one. Things get considerably more complicated when I have to restore defaults to just one, but not the others.

My math skills are not that sharp, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve.  Are you saying you want to generate random numbers and put them into bins of different size to tailor the probabilities associated with each bin?  To keep things simple assume a range [0..9]. If I have 5 bins of width 2, then each bin has a 20% chance of being selected.  If I make 3 bins of width 3, 5 and 2 then the bins have probabilities of 30%, 50% and 20%.  Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I believe that's it.

Comment: @JimGarrison Actually, that's exactly it. Only the number of bins is variable and so are their lengths. That's what is making things complicated.

Comment: @JimGarrison If you think about it, every time you increase the size of one bin, the sizes of each other bin must decrease or the value will be out of range.

Comment: @JimGarrison It's a very complicated thing to solve, and I'm willing to do it, but I want to make sure there isn't a better mathematical solution. All I'm trying to do is put modifiers on the %likelihood of a given bin.

Comment: Not if you don't use a fixed range.  The range is the sum of all your bin sizes.  If you have 3 bins that add up to 10 use the range [0..9].  With 6 bins that add up to 27 use range [0..26].  Then it's a simple search up a list of bin sizes, or prepopulate an array from 0 to the range with bin numbers for an O(1) search.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without changing the random value?

Comment: Or you are saying I should set that value to the sum of all bins /before/ I roll? That actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I see what you are saying though: increase the max random and therefore the other bins don't have to change size. It's good, I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it.

1. Determine the sizes of the bins to achieve the desired distribution.
2. Determine the *sum* of the sizes of all the bins, call it `n`
3. Allocate an `int[] slots = new int[n];`
4. Pre-populate the array such that each slot contains the bin number
5. Generate a random number between 0 and `n-1` inclusive, called `x`
6. Read the bin number from `slots[x]`

Comment: Wait, no, there is still the same problem.

Comment: x and y represent values, if I just make one bigger without re-sizing the others, there will be overlap between bins.

Comment: So you have to scale things to preserve relative probabilities. You can still use this approach to do things dynamically.  You have to decide the bin widths and relative probabilities _somewhere_, and it is simplest to just provide a list of bin widths.  Those you have to calculate yourself because only you know what relative probabilities you want.  The simplest way to _implement_ this to enter only the bin widths and use the procedure I outlined.  You let the algorithm translate bin widths into a data structure for quick access.

Comment: The sizes of the bins change. This is the problem. If the bins were A, B, C and D, all at 25%, if I want to increase A to 30%, even if I increase the max size of the array, all of the x,y values have to be changed. Unless you are lucky enough to be increasing a bin at the end.

Comment: I don't see a solution there, but I dunno... maybe if you code it out?

Comment: Sorry, you write the code.  For the case you gave (A,B,C,D) with A=30%, how do you decide what B, C and D are?

Comment: If Amin=0, Amax=25, Bmin=25, Bmax=50, Cmin=50, Cmax=75, Dmin=75, Dmax=100. So if I want to increase Amax + 5, that means that Bmin must become 30, Bmax55, and so on.

Comment: Every element of the array has to be touched to change one value, and the maximum also has to be increased.

Comment: So your bin sizes are now (30,25,25,25) and the total is now 105.  Go back to my answer and see how this works.  I cannot explain it better.

Comment: How are you populating the array?

Comment: If the  array is int[] = {30, 25, 25, 25}, and I grab a value between 0-100 and index it, it will go out of bounds. Eg. int[75]. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You input `{30, 25, 25, 25}` and your code generates an array `int[105]` containing 30 zeroes followed by 25 values `1`, 25 values `2` and 25 values `3`.  Then you generate a random in the range [0..104] and index the `int[105]` array to read out the bin number.  Good night.

Comment: With only four cases that's not bad, but if I have 10 or 20, it's a huge block of memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105096/discussion-between-jim-garrison-and-bigcodeszzer).